# Xcode keeps losing connection to my IPad

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, sprite-kit

I'm having a very frustrating problem. Everytime I run my Spritekit game on my device, Xcode will lose its connection to my device. Sometimes in the beginning of the game but most of the time when the game ends or I try to switch from an SKScene to a ViewController scene. I tried researching the problem on here and other sites and programmers keep suggesting that it's a signing issue and for me to possibly create a new provisioning profile, as that may solve the issue. I just did that and the problem still persists. Is this problem common with running on IPads? Could the problem be more severe in nature? Can somebody please help?

Comment: It looks to me more like a hardware issue. I used to encounter such an issue with my old iPhone and I just resolved it by changing a better cable.

Comment: are you using perhaps some of the new beta soft? like Xcode 7 or iOS 9?